# Actualizar una tabla con ajax

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

Como puedo actualizar una tabla utilizando `ajax`, 
tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
$("#venta").bootstrapTable({
                url:'<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemlo/usuarios/datos'
                columns:[
                  {field: 'reStatus'},
                  {field: 'ocTipoUs'},
                  {field: 'faClave'},
                  {field: 'tiPeso'},
                  {field: 'inpo'}
                ],

                pagination: true,
                showFooter: true,
                search: true,
                showExport:true,
                filter: true,
                method: 'post',
                showRefresh:true,
                pageList:[10, 25, 50, 100, 'All'],
                showPaginationSwitch: true
                });
            });
```

La tabla se forma con los datos del `json`, el problema es al aplicar un filtro de fechas, mando los datos, se hace  la consulta y me trae los nuevos datos pero no se como puedo pintar la tabla con los nuevos datos del `json`.

Answer (score -1):

Revisa este ejemplo

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function(event) {
   var nombreVar = $('#nombre').val();
   var apellidoVar = $('#apellido').val();
   var edadVar = $('#edad').val();
   $.post('ActionServlet', {
    nombre : nombreVar,
    apellido: apellidoVar,
    edad: edadVar
   }, function(responseText) {
    $('#tabla').html(responseText);
   });
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Ejemplo de AJAX con JSP y Servelts</h2>
 <form id="form1">
  Nombre:<input type="text" id="nombre" /> <br>
  Apellido: <input type="text" id="apellido" /> <br>
  Edad: <input type="text" id="edad" /> <br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Añadir" /> 
 </form>
 <br>
 <div id="tabla"></div>
</body>
```

Interviene un archivo java, donde tienes tu clase Persona y grabas los valores

```html
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
  
  response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" );
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  
  // Obtengo los datos de la peticion
  String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
  String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
  String edad = request.getParameter("edad");
  
  if (!nombre.equals("") && !apellido.equals("") && !edad.equals("")) {
   // Creo el objeto persona y lo añado al arrayList
   Persona persona = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad);
   personas.add(persona);
  }
  
  out.println("<table style= cellspacing=\"1\" bgcolor=\"#0099cc\">");
  out.println("<tr>");
  out.println("<td style= rowspan=\"7\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f8f8f8\"> NOMBRE </td>");   
  out.println("<td style= rowspan=\"7\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f8f8f8\">APELLIDO</td>");
  out.println("<td style= rowspan=\"7\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f8f8f8\">EDAD</td>");
  out.println("</tr>");
  for(int i=0; i<personas.size(); i++){
   Persona persona = personas.get(i);
   out.println("<tr>");
   out.println("<td style= rowspan=\"7\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f8f8f8\">"+persona.getNombre()+"</td>");   
   out.println("<td style= rowspan=\"7\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f8f8f8\">"+persona.getApellido()+"</td>");
   out.println("<td style= rowspan=\"7\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f8f8f8\">"+persona.getEdad()+"</td>");
   out.println("</tr>");
  }
  out.println("</table>");  
  
 }
```

Comment: Esto que tiene que ver con PHP y ajax? No es necesario java para eso